# Under what circumstances does the read() syscall return 0?

Tags: linux, unix, system-calls

I'm looking at the `read` syscall in Unix, which (at least in Linux) has this signature: [1]

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void* buf, size_t count);
```

Let's assume that the call succeeds (i.e. no negative return values) and that `count > 0` (i.e. the buffer actually can store a nonzero amount of bytes). Under which circumstances would `read()` return 0? I can think of the following:

- When `fd` refers to a regular file and the end of the file has been reached.
- When `fd` refers to the receiving end of a pipe, socket or FIFO, the sending end has been closed and the pipe's/socket's/FIFO's own buffer has been exhausted.
- When `fd` refers to the slave side of a terminal device that is in `ICANON` and `Ctrl-D` has been sent into the master side while the line buffer was empty.

I'm curious if there are any other situations that I'm not aware of, where `read()` would return with a result of 0. I'm especially interested (because of reasons) in situations like the last one in the list above, where `read()` returns 0 once, but subsequent calls to `read()` on the same FD could return a nonzero result. If an answer only applies to a certain flavor of Unix, I'm still interested in hearing it.

[1] I know this signature is for the libc wrapper, not the actual syscall, but that's not important right now.

Comment: It happens for regular files if the file has been appended to since the previous read returned 0.

Comment: `0` is always considered to be "end of file". It's just that for some types of streams, this can be a temporary condition.

Comment: "In the absence of errors, or if error detection is not performed, the read() function shall return zero and have no other results."[1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html)

Comment: @vv01f That's only if `nbyte == 0`

Comment: indeed, the document names other cases for "shall return 0"

Comment: In z/OS: (1) If the Physical File System does not support simple reads from directories, read() will return 0 if it is used for a directory. (2) If the starting position for the read operation is at the end of the file or **beyond**, read() returns 0. [doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/rtrea.htm)

Answer (score 8):

- If the Physical File System does not support simple reads from directories, read() will return 0 if it is used for a directory.
- If no process has the pipe open for writing, read() returns 0 to indicate the end of the file.
- If the connection is broken on a stream socket, but no data is available, then the read() function returns 0 bytes as EOF.

Comment: The only thing here that I didn't mention yet is the empty read on fds backed by directories (which, as far as I've been told, is also not portable; some obscure Unices return stuff from read() on directories). So sorry, but that's not worth the +200 bounty IMO.

Comment: @StefanMajewsky I don't think there are any other cases other than special conditions of your points #2 and #3.

Comment: I don't disagree.

Comment: You missed: if `read` from a regular file whose file pointer is at 0 bytes from `SEEK_END`

Answer (score 0):

Normally a return value of `0` always means end-of-file. However, if you specify `0` as the number of bytes to read, it will always return `0` unless there's an error detected.

Terminal devices are a special case. If the terminal is in cooked mode, typing <kbd>Control-d</kbd> tells the device driver to return from any pending `read()` immediately with whatever is in the input editing buffer, rather than waiting for the user to enter a newline. If the buffer is empty, this results in a zero-length read. This is how typing the EOF character at the beginning of a line is automatically treated as EOF by applications.

Comment: Both these are already mentioned in the question (`count > 0` is specified, and bullet 3 is C-d on a tty).