# read(fd, buf, N>0) == 0, but fd not at EOF?

Tags: c, posix, aix, rlwrap

The following little C program (let's call it `pointless`):

```
/* pointless.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(){
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, "", 0); /* pointless write() of 0 bytes */
  sleep(1);
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, "still there!\n", 13);
}
```

will print "still there!" after a small delay, as expected. However,
`rlwrap ./pointless` prints nothing under AIX and exits immediatly.

Apparently, `rlwrap` reads 0 bytes after the first `write()` and
(incorrectly) decides that `pointless` has called it quits.

When running `pointless` without `rlwrap`, and *with* `rlwrap` on all
other systems I could lay my hand on (Linux, OSX, FreeBSD), the "still
there!" gets printed, as expected.

The relevant `rlwrap` (pseudo-)code is this:

```
/* master is  the file descriptor of the master end of a pty, while the slave is 'pointless's stdout   */
/* master was opened with O_NDELAY                                                                     */
while(pselect(nfds, &readfds, .....)) {
   if (FD_ISSET(master, &readfds)) {           /* master is "ready" for reading       */
      nread = read(master, buf, BUFFSIZE - 1); /* so try to read a buffer's worth     */
      if (nread == 0)                          /* 0 bytes read...                     */
         cleanup_and_exit();                   /* ... usually means EOF, doens't it?  */
```

Apparently, on all systems, except AIX, `write`ing 0 bytes on the
slave end of a pty is a no-op, while on AIX it wakes up the
`select()` on the master end. Writing 0 bytes seems pointless, but one
of my test programs writes random-length chunks of text, which may
actually happen to have length 0.

On linux, `man 2 read` states "on success, the number of bytes read is
returned *(zero indicates end of file)*" (italics are mine) This
question has [come up
before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411385/under-what-circumstances-does-the-read-syscall-return-0)
without mention of this scenario.

This begs the question: how can I *portably* determine whether the
slave end has been closed? (In this case I can probably just wait for
a `SIGCHLD` and then close shop, but that might open another can of
worms I'd rather avoid)

---

Edit: [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) states:

> Writing a zero-length buffer (nbyte is 0) to a STREAMS device sends 0 bytes with 0 returned. However, writing a zero-length buffer to a STREAMS-based pipe or FIFO sends no message and 0 is returned. The process may issue I_SWROPT ioctl() to enable zero-length messages to be sent across the pipe or FIFO.

On AIX, `pty` is indeed a STREAMS device, moreover, not a pipe or FIFO. `ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, I_SWROPT, 0)` seems to make it possible to make the pty conform to the rest of the Unix world. The sad thing is that this has to be called from the *slave* side, and so is outside `rlwrap`s sphere of infuence (even though we could call the `ioctl()` between `fork()` and `exec()` - that would not guarantee that the executed command won't change it back)

Comment: [Per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html): "When attempting to read from an empty pipe or FIFO:

    If no process has the pipe open for writing, read() shall return 0 to indicate end-of-file."  So the "read of zero bytes means EOF" is POSIX-compliant.

Comment: Yes, I saw that too. My problem is: it states _if at EOF, then return 0_.  But it doesn't say  _if 0 is returned, you may assume EOF_. However, the prhrase _to indicate end-of-file_ seems to imply that de implication indeed can be read both ways.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you try `ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, I_SWROPT, 0)` at the beginning of `pointless.c` on AIX and see what happens? ([why I think this may change the behavior](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/ioctl.htm))

Comment: @Sergey_Kalinichenko: good one. I'l try it when I have time again...

Comment: @Sergey_Kalinichenko: `ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, I_SWROPT, 0)` does the trick! When I insert it at the beginning of `pointless.c` `rlwrap` doesn't  return from the `pselect()` when `pointless` does the 0-bit `write`. I think I will use this between `fork()` and `execute()` on the slave side of the pty. Thanks a lot for the tip! In theory, the client program could undo the `ioctl()`, but this bug has gone unnoticed for over 20 years, so the sollution doesn't have to be perfect.....

Answer (score 2):

From the [linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)

> If count is zero and fd refers to a regular file, then write()
> may return a failure status if one of the errors below is
> detected.  If no errors are detected, or error detection is not
> performed, 0 will be returned without causing any other effect.
> If count is zero and fd refers to a file other than a regular
> file, the results are not specified.

So, since it is unspecified, it can do whatever it likes in your case.

Comment: Your IBM link is for z/OS.

Comment: Yes. But in POSIX its undefined behaviour you are relying on. So it can work in one case but not in the other, as you experienced.

Comment: The z/OS link states "If N is zero, write() simply returns 0 without attempting any other action."  That's not what's happening on AIX.

Comment: Undefined is undefined. I removed that link to IBM, as it was only to show that you have different behaviour depending on the OS BECAUSE it is undefined.

Comment: Umm, "unspecified' is not the same thing as "undefined".

Answer (score 2):

[Per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html):

> When attempting to read from an empty pipe or FIFO:
>
> - If no process has the pipe open for writing, read() shall return 0 to indicate end-of-file."

So the "read of zero bytes means EOF" is POSIX-compliant.

On [the `write()` side](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) (bolding mine):

> Before any action described below is taken, and if `nbyte` is zero and the file is a regular file, the `write()` function may detect and return errors as described below. In the absence of errors, or if error detection is not performed, the `write()` function shall return zero and have no other results. **If `nbyte` is zero and the file is not a regular file, the results are unspecified.**

Unfortunately, that means you can't portably depend on a `write()` of zero bytes to have no effect because AIX is compliant with the POSIX standard for `write()` here.

You probably have to rely on `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: This is the key point. Don't call `write` with `nbytes==0` unless you want to deal with the unspecified, possibly implementation-specific consequences of doing so.

Comment: The point is that I, as `rlwrap` maintainer,  encounter programs that _do_ stuff like calling `write` with `nbytes = 0`. Of course I could just say that those programs are doing it wrong, but they _exist_ so I'll have to deal with them....

Comment: @HansLub [`isastream()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isastream.html) might prove useful.